# jQuery: how to select attribue in this situation?

Tags: jquery, xml

In my jQuery ajax method, the "data" it returns as following format:

```
<root>
    <result sender='BlackSmith' nickName='Blac'></result>
    <result sender='AristleJohnson' nickName='AJ'></result>
    .
    .
    .
</root>
```

In my jQuery function, my code is:

```
$(data).find('result').each(function(){ 
    alert("test");//it never shows up, I don't know why?
    var userId=$(this).attr('sender');
    var nickName=$(this).attr('nickName');
});
```

However, the alert never shows up, which means $(data).find('result') does not work here. Could you help me? Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure, which is why this is a comment, but it's possible that your code isn't returning anything due to the result being a string. Don't take my word for it though.

Comment: I copy/pasted code above and it works, perfectly. So it's probably a scope issue. Please paste bit more of your jQuery.

Comment: Works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/TyBxf/ The problem is somewhere in the code you did not post. Also make sure that the XML is valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can pass HTML/XML into jQuery as you are with $(data). Typically, the DOM in question is already on the page somewhere, and you do $("result") instead.

In your case, you should dataType to "xml" in the ajax request itself, and then jQuery will actually parse the results and [give them to you in your success() handler](http://think2loud.com/224-reading-xml-with-jquery/).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/sites.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
            $(xml).find('result').each(function(){
                    ...
                });
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't use dataType:"xml", so it does not parse it as a xml data.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're assigning the return value of the ajax call to the data variable, everything looks good - some things to check:

- Try explicitly setting the dataType as XML
- Double check what you're getting back from the server and that the response isn't 500ing, 404ing, or returning an empty response for any other reason

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is that your dataset doesn't actually contain the response. Is `$(data).find...` actually inside the AJAX call? Once you leave the scope of the `success:` function, your response will be destroyed.

So most importantly, check scope:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "[yoururl]",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(data) {
          //this is the only place your $(data) selector will work...
    }
});
```

If you want to use data elsewhere, you're going to have to pass it out of your ajax call.